# How does Linux deal with depreciation? What does depreciation mean to Linux?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

What is the term depreciation and what does it mean to Linux?

Comment: This isn't a Linux Q&A site, Stack Exchange *Unix & Linux* performs that function, this is the Ubuntu and *official flavors of Ubuntu* Q&A site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and all releases of Ubuntu-GNOME are now EOL as the *flavor* ended when Ubuntu switched back to GNOME by default (17.10) and the last LTS release of Ubuntu-GNOME reached EOL in 2019.

Comment: "depreciation" is a fiscal accounting term, not a computer science term. Perhaps you mean "deprecation"

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what #3 in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate states.

> 3   : to withdraw official support for or discourage the use of (something, such as a software product) in favor of a newer or better alternative

When they deprecate an application it is indeed to move one to something better.  `apt-key` has been deprecated in Ubuntu 20.10, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't work still, it is that they are going to officially end support for it in favor of `signed-by`.  `ifconfig` is another example of a deprecated app that is no longer getting official support but still works.  It has been deprecated for `ip`.  The list goes on.

Hope this helps shed some light.